# How can float use as much memory as long (32 bits), but store much more numbers?

Tags: floating-point, long-integer

Long int have range from -2147483648 to 2147483647. It uses 32 bits of memory. Float has range of -3.4E+38 to +3.4E+38, yet it is the same size. How can this be possible?

Answer (score 2):

`float` does not exactly encode every integer value [-2147483648 to 2147483647].  About [3.9%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60060264/how-can-float-use-as-much-memory-as-long-32-bits-but-store-much-more-numbers/60060403?noredirect=1#comment106229160_60060403) of them.  Review [binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).

Comment: 3.90625 percent.

Comment: All of them from 0 to 16,777,215 (2^24). Then, for those in the binade [2^24, 2^25), 8,388,608 (2^23, due to 23 bits in explicit significand field), and also 2^23 for each binade starting with 2^25, 2^26, 2^27, 2^28, 2^29, 2^30, and 2^31, so 8 binades. Thus 2^24 + 8•2^23, which is 83,886,080. For the negative numbers, −0 is already counted as +0, but we have −2^24, so the same number, and a total of 167,772,160 which is 3.90625% of 2^32.